# Count of unique clicks (SQL query)

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, count, distinct

I have an email delivery system in my service (for my email subscribers). I need to get statistic information about sent messages, clicks and opening counts for my emails. All information stores in **PostgreSQL** database.

I have a table with my subscriber lists (`subscriber_collections`):

```
_id name
===========
 1  MySubscribers
 2  VIP Subscribers
```

So I have a table which stores emails for each subscriber list (`emails`, one-to-many relation)

```
_id  subscriber_collection_id  email_address
===========================================
 1               1              john.smith@email.com
 2               1              james3@email.com
 3               1              jay10@email.com
 4               2              second@email.com
 5               2              john.smith@email.com
 6               2              jay10@email.com
```

Also I have a table `mail_activities` which stores information about different email activities (such as clicks, opens, sends, etc...).:

```
_id  message_id  message_subject  activity_date   email_address       type
============================================================================
 1      25           Hello msg!    2017-11-21   john.smith@email.com  Sends
 2      25           Hello msg!    2017-11-21   john.smith@email.com  Opens
 3      25           Hello msg!    2017-11-21   john.smith@email.com  Clicks
 4      25           Hello msg!    2017-11-21   jay10@email.com       Clicks
 5      25           Hello msg!    2017-11-21   jay10@email.com       Clicks
 6      16           Discount!     2017-11-21   second@email.com      Opens
 7      16           Discount!     2017-11-21   second@email.com      Opens
 8      16           Discount!     2017-11-21   james3@email.com      Opens
```

Note that the user can repeatedly click (or open) on the same email and the information will be in the database.

I have a SQL query, which gets count of different activities for each email messages and subscriber collections:

```
SELECT
    MA.message_id
    ,MA.message_subject
    ,SC.name as subscriber_collection_name
    ,MA.date AS activity_date
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN MA.type='Sends' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as sends_count
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN MA.type='Opens' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as opens_count
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN MA.type='Clicks' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as clicks_count
FROM
    mail_activities MA
    INNER JOIN emails E ON MA.email_address = E.email_address
    INNER JOIN subscriber_collections SC ON E.subscriber_collection_id = SC._id

GROUP BY
    MA.message_id
    ,MA.message_subject
    ,SC._id
    ,SC.name
    ,MA.date                    
ORDER BY
    message_id
```

This query works fine. Here is result for this data:

[image: result of SQL-query]

**QUESTION:** I need to get **count of unique clicks and opens activities for each `email_address`**. This information I need to get as additional columns in that query (`unique_clicks` and `unique_opens`). For example, two clicks on letter `Hello msg!` by user `jay10@email.com` in table `emails` should be perceived as one. How can I get this information in additional columns? Thanks...

**P.S:** Sorry for my bad english...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use a conditional `count(distinct)`:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MA.type = 'Sends' THEN ma.message_id END) as sends_unique_count
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MA.type = 'Opens' THEN ma.message_id END) as opens_unique_count
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MA.type = 'Clicks' THEN ma.message_id END) as clicks_unique_count
```

I'm not quite sure how this fits into your existing query, though.  You want unique counts per email (it seems by the description), but you are aggregating by `message_id`.

Hmmm . . . perhaps you want distinct email addresses:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MA.type = 'Sends' THEN ma.email_address END) as sends_unique_count
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MA.type = 'Opens' THEN ma.email_address END) as opens_unique_count
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MA.type = 'Clicks' THEN ma.email_address END) as clicks_unique_count
```